# When does the mass leave the spring-connected pan?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, spring

[image]

Upper mass: $M$, lower mass: $m$, normal force between them: $N$.

When the masses are in contact, 
$$\frac{N-Mg}M =\frac{kx-N-mg}m$$
$$ N=\frac{Mkx}{m+M}$$

At the moment they lose contact, $N=0$.
$$\frac{Mkx}{m+M}=0$$

Solving it gives $x=0$. However, the answer should be $3.9$ cm.

Actually, I predicted that I have to take a limit of $m\to 0$ at last. It turns out that my amswer is independent of $m$.

What mistakes did I make?

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that this site is not a place to obtain solutions to worked problems. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work problems"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not even sure how you have managed to divide by $m$ in the first equation and if $m$ zero (notice - *light* pan). I'm unsure what the first equation represents at all. I can just give some hints, which are easily solving this task (I've checked).

**So, what's happening here**? Once the pan passes the point of equilibrium while going up, the Hooke's force is equal to zero and nothing is slowing the pan; as the pan approaches the topmost position, the pan is slowing with an increasing rate since the Hooke's force is growing. The ball is also slowing, though it's slowing at the constant rate, since $g=9.8~m/s$ is constant.

At some point of time, the Hooke's force becomes smaller than the gravity force, and at this time the pan is already slowing with a greater rate than the ball, so the ball leaves the pan.

This analysis will lead you to the correct answer.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's right to answer such questions or they should be closed.

Comment: but $m$ is the one for the light pan...I attached my work because I just hoped others can point out my mistake clearly...hope that wouldn’t make my question getting closed.

Comment: @Szeto you have misunderstood the definition of "light". "light" means "has ***zero*** mass".

Comment: Well, I thought considering non zero mass then taking the limit of $m\to 0$ wouldn’t affect the answer.

Comment: @Szeto could you tell me what law does the first sentence represent? Why are you dividing by masses?

Comment: Thank you for your patience. The equation represents that before they lose contact, their accelerations are the same.

Comment: @Szeto $N$ is supposed to be the reaction of the support? There's only one support, which is the pan, and I'm missing the point of including $N$ in l.h.s. and r.h.s. with different signs.

Comment: Since I’m considering the pan’s mass as non zero, for the two objects to attain the same acceleration, a normal force acts between the two objects, in opposite directions. Defining upwards as positive, a downward normal force $-N$ acts on the pan, and as a consequence of Newton’s 3rd law, an upward $+N$ force acts on the upper mass.

Comment: @Szeto all in all, I'm not sure, if not against, to consider the mass to be non-zero and then take the limit. This is weird, I haven't seen that it has been done this way. The phrase "light" doesn't state the mass is *close* to zero. It states that the mass is *exactly* zero, not in the limit and not close to it.

Comment: @Szeto have you got the answer though?

Comment: Well, I’ve done a lot of problems about classical mechanics and electrodynamics and taking limits often works, since physics is usually continuous. I am going to rethink the whole thing and either come up with a solution with limits or find out the reason that limit fails.

Comment: Solving the problem with $m>0$ is legitimate and also $m \rightarrow 0$ should work fine. Your approach can be applied directly to an horizontal spring for example. For the vertical spring, you should carefully examine your definition of $x$. You are explicitly accounting for $mg$ and $Mg$, so $x$ cannot be defined relative to the equilibrium point. Rather, it should be defined relative to the un-streched point. With both $m$ and $M$, the equations may become messy and @nicael approach is easier to solve.